Rabinowitz-Wagon \$\pi\$ formula
In 1995, Stanley Rabinowitz and Stan Wagon found an interesting algorithm to generate the digits of \$\pi\$ one by one without storing the previous results. The algorithm is called the spigot algorithm. It is based on the following formula:
$$ \pi = 2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{3} \left(1 + \frac{2}{5} \left(1 + \frac{3}{7} \left(1 + \cdots \frac{k}{2k+1} \left(1 + \cdots\right)\right)\right)\right)\right) $$
This formula can be derived from the Leibniz formula for \$\pi\$ using the Euler's transformation.
(The formula was already well-known before the algorithm was found, but I can't find a name for it. So I call it the Rabinowitz-Wagon \$\pi\$ formula as @aeh5040 suggested in a sandbox comment.)
Using this formula, we can approximate \$\pi\$ by a sequence of fractions. The first few terms are:
$$\begin{aligned}
2 &= 2, \\
\frac{8}{3} &= 2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{3}\right), \\
\frac{44}{15} &= 2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{3} \left(1 + \frac{2}{5}\right)\right), \\
\frac{64}{21} &= 2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{3} \left(1 + \frac{2}{5} \left(1 + \frac{3}{7}\right)\right)\right), \\
\dots&\dots
\end{aligned}$$
Task
In this challenge, you need to output this sequence of fractions.
You can output a fraction \$\frac{a}{b}\$ in any reasonable format, e.g. a built-in rational type, a pair of integers \$(a, b)\$, or a string a/b. You don't need to simplify the fraction. For example, you can output \$\frac{8}{3}\$ as \$\frac{40}{15}\$.
As with standard sequence challenges, you may choose to:

Take an integer \$n\$ as input and output the \$n\$th term of the sequence.
Take an integer \$n\$ as input and output the first \$n\$ terms of the sequence.
Take no input and output the sequence indefinitely.

The indices can be 0-based or 1-based.
This is code-golf, so the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.
Test cases
0 -> 2
1 -> 8/3
2 -> 44/15
3 -> 64/21
4 -> 976/315
5 -> 10816/3465
6 -> 141088/45045
7 -> 47104/15015
8 -> 2404096/765765
9 -> 45693952/14549535
10 -> 45701632/14549535
11 -> 80863232/25741485
12 -> 5256312832/1673196525
13 -> 3153846272/1003917915
14 -> 457311809536/145568097675
15 -> 833925152768/265447707525
16 -> 4725585805312/1504203675975
17 -> 14176771899392/4512611027925
18 -> 524540820979712/166966608033225
19 -> 104908189597696/33393321606645


Python, 71 70 60 57 bytes
f=lambda n,q=1,p=1:n and f(n-1,q:=q*2*n+q,p*n+q)or(2*p,q)

Attempt This Online!
Outputs the (0-indexed) nth term of the sequence as a (numerator, denominator) tuple.
Ungolfed algorithm:
def f(n):
    numerator, denominator = 1, 1
    # i/(2i + 1) = n/(2n + 1), ..., 3/7, 2/5, 1/3
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        # multiply by i/(2i + 1)
        numerator *= i
        denominator *= 2 * i + 1
        # add 1 (p/q -> (p + q)/q = p/q + q/q = p/q + 1)
        numerator += denominator
    return 2 * numerator, denominator

For n=3:
  * 3/7     + 1      * 2/5       + 1       * 1/3        + 1         * 2
1 ----> 3/7 --> 10/7 ----> 20/35 --> 55/35 ----> 55/105 --> 160/105 --> 320/105


J, 14 bytes
2#.~1%2+1%]-i.

Attempt This Online!
If we expand the formula entirely, we get 2 + 2*1/3 + 2*1/3*2/5 + 2*1/3*2/5*3/7 + ..., which can be interpreted as a mixed base conversion of [..., 2, 2, 2, 2] in base [..., 3/7, 2/5, 1/3].

J, 19 bytes
2(*>:)/@,1%2+1%1+i.

Attempt This Online!
A straightforward implementation of the formula. Takes an arbitrary-precision integer, constructs the array that looks like 2 1/3 2/5 3/7, and reduces from the right by x * (1 + y).
J, 20 bytes
(>:@+:#.0&=,:2*!)@i.

Attempt This Online!
Tried to be clever with some mixed-base magic:
(1 + 1/3(1 + 2/5)) * 3*5 = 3*5 + 1*5 + 1*2
(1 + 1/3(1 + 2/5(1 + 3/7))) * 3*5*7 = 3*5*7 + 1*5*7 + 1*2*7 + 1*2*3

So the numerator can be computed by evaluating [0!, 1!, 2!, 3!, ...] in mixed base [1, 3, 5, 7, ...]. Then the denominator can also be represented using [1, 0, 0, 0, ...]. Might be useful in languages without rational number support.

K (ngn/k), 24 bytes
2 1*1(|+\|*)/+-\(1-)\!-:

Try it online!
Input n. Return the \$n\$th term as an integer pair.

M, 11 bytes
RḤ‘İ×R×\S‘Ḥ

Try it online!
Interestingly enough, the Jelly equivalent (which doesn't have rational number support) is only 1 byte longer. The TIO link demonstrates the results for each input \$0\$ to \$n\$.
How it works
RḤ‘İ×R×\S‘Ḥ - Main link. Takes an integer n on the left
R           - Generate the range [1, 2, ..., n]
 Ḥ          - Unhalve; [2, 4, ..., 2n]
  ‘         - Increment; [3, 5, ..., 2n+1]
   İ        - Inverse; [1/3, 1/5, ..., 1/2n+1]
     R      - Range; [1, 2, ..., n]
    ×       - Multiply; [1/3, 2/5, ..., n/2n+1]
       \    - Scan by:
      ×     -   Product; [1/3, 1/3×2/5, ...]
        S   - Sum; 1/3 + 1/3×2/5 + ...
         ‘  - Increment; 1 + 1/3 + 1/3×2/5 + ...
          Ḥ - Unhalve; 2 + 2×1/3 + 2×1/3×2/5 + ...


Ruby, 38 35 bytes
->n{(z=2)+(1..n).sum{|x|z/=2+1r/x}}

Try it online!

That's very elegant!

Vyxal s, 51 bitsv2, 6.375 bytes
ƛƛd›/;Πd

Try it Online!
Bitstring:
000001100001010101101101100001101101001010101111101

Ports the expanded formula from Bubbler's J answer.
Explained
ƛƛd›/;Πd­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
ƛ         # ‎⁡Over each n in the range [1, in]:
 ƛ   ;    # ‎⁢  Over each m in the range [1, n]:
    /     # ‎⁣    m divided by
  d›      # ‎⁤    2m + 1
      Π   # ‎⁢⁡  Product of each fraction
       d  # ‎⁢⁢  Doubled
# ‎⁢⁣Summed by the s flag


Created with the help of Luminespire.

Charcoal, 27 bytes
ＮθＩＥ²ΣＥ∨ι⊕θΠ⊕⊞ＯＥθ⎇‹νλν⊗⊕ν¬ι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Directly computes the numerator and denominator, inspired by @Bubbler's last approach.
Ｎθ                          Input as a number
    ²                       Literal integer `2`
   Ｅ                        Map over implicit range
        ι                   Current value
       ∨                    Logical Or
          θ                 Input number
         ⊕                  Incremented
      Ｅ                     Map over implicit range
                θ           Input number
               Ｅ            Map over implicit range
                   ν        Innermost value
                  ‹         Is less than
                    λ       Inner value
                 ⎇          If true then
                     ν      Innermost value
                        ν   Else innermost value
                       ⊕    Incremented
                      ⊗     Doubled
             ⊞Ｏ             Append
                          ι Current (outer) value
                         ¬  Incremented
            ⊕               Vectorised increment
           Π                Take the product
     Σ                      Take the sum
  Ｉ                         Cast to string
                            Implicitly print


PARI/GP, 28 bytes
n->(z=2)+sum(i=1,n,z/=2+1/i)

Attempt This Online!
A port of @G B's Ruby answer.
\$0\$-indexed. Returns a rational number.

PARI/GP, 43 bytes
n->prod(i=0,n,[i+2*!i,!!i*k=2*i+1;0,k])[,2]

Attempt This Online!
\$1\$-indexed. Returns a column vector of numerator and denominator.
Using the fact that composition of linear fractional transformations (\$x\mapsto\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\$) corresponds to matrix multiplication.
The \$n\$-th output is \$\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\0&3\end{bmatrix}\cdots\begin{bmatrix}n&2n+1\\0&2n+1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\$.

Raku (Perl 6) (rakudo), 49 43 bytes
{2+2*[+] [\*] map {.FatRat/(2*$_+1)},1..$_}

Attempt This Online!

JavaScript (Node.js), 43 bytes
f=(n,p=q=1)=>n?f(n-1,p*n+(q*=n-~n)):[p*2,q]

Attempt This Online!
Port of shape warrior t's answer

R, 74 61 bytes
`~`=\(n,m=1)`if`(m>n,1,(a=n~m+1)[1]*(2*m+1)+m*a*0:1)*1:2^!m-1

Attempt This Online!
Recursive approach to construct the Rabinowitz-Wagon formula as stated in the question.
Outputs the (0-based) n-th non-simplified fraction of the sequence as two integers in the order (denominator, numerator).
Ungolfed:
f=function(n){
    g=function(n,m=1){
        if(m>n)c(1,1) else {
            x=g(n,m+1)
            a=x[1];b=x[2]
            c(2*m*b+b+m*a,2*m*b+b)
        }
    }
    g(n)*2:1
}


R, 62 60 54 bytes
\(n){a=1
if(n)for(i in n:1)a=a*i+(T=T*2*i+T)
c(2*a,T)}

Attempt This Online!
Port of shape warrior t's answer

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 63 45 bytes
Saved 18 bytes thanks to @att

Golfed version. Try it online!
{2,1}Dot@@Array[{{#,a=2#+1},{0,a}}&,#].{0,1}&

Ungolfed version. Try it online!
(*Define the matrix for a given n*)
matrixForN[n_] := {{n, 2   n + 1}, {0, 2   n + 1}}

(*Compute the product of matrices from n=1 to m*)
productOfMatrices[m_] := 
 Fold[Dot, {{2, 0}, {0, 1}}, Table[matrixForN[n], {n, m}]]

(*Apply the final matrix to the vector {0,1}*)
f[m_] := productOfMatrices[m] . {0, 1}

(*Print the results for n=1 to 20*)
Table[{n, f[n]}, {n, 1, 20}] // 
 Do[Print[ele[[1]], " -> ", ele[[2]][[1]], "/", ele[[2]][[2]]], {ele, #}] &


-18

R, 84 bytes
\(n,m=0:n*2+1)cbind(Reduce(\(a,b)a*b+2*prod(1:((b-1)/2)),c(2,m),,,T)[-1],cumprod(m))

Attempt This Online!
An anonymous function that takes an integer \$n\$ and outputs the first \$n+1\$ fractions of Rabinowitz-Wagon -formula as two columns side by side - the numerator and the denominator, respectively.

APL(Dyalog Unicode),  31 2724 21 bytes SBCS
It outputs the \$n\$th term with the denominator comes before the numerator. Assumes ⎕io←0. 24 -> 21 bytes thanks to @att.
∊2(×∘(+⍀)⌿⊣@0,⍨¨1+×)⍳

Try it on APLgolf!
Try it on APLgolf! (24bytes)
Try it on APLgolf! (27bytes)
Try it on APLgolf! (31bytes)

21: ∊2(×∘(+⍀)⌿⊣@0,⍨¨1+×)⍳

Kap: 21 characters
(1+)⍛×/⌽2,÷∘(1+2×)1+⍳

This function takes n, and returns a rational number. This takes advantage of the built-in support for rational numbers in Kap, where dividing integers always yields a rational. To convert the result to floating point, one can add 0.0 to the result.

## APL, 36 bytes
This is a function that takes n as input and outputs a pair of integers representing the numerator and denominator of the answer:
{{⍺×⍵+⍵[2]0}/(⊂2 1),(⊢,1+2∘×)¨⍳⍵}
APL, 32 bytes
Updated Solution:: ⎕←{⍺×⍵+⍵[2]0}/(⊂2 1),(⊢,1++⍨)¨⍳⎕ - I converted from a function to stdin & stdout, and used suggestion by akamayu (converted 2∘× → +⍨ to save a byte).
Try it online!
I'll try to shorten it by using more tacit style to remove named arguments - any suggestions are welcome .

Nice answer! 2∘× → +⍨ saves a byte. You can add a link to https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf so others can check the answer more easily. It can count the bytes and generate the post for you .

@akamayu Thanks , edited my answer to use your suggestion
